# BASH Scripting, su to www-data for single command

Tags: ubuntu, bash, svn, su

I am working on automating the creation of subversion repositories and associated websites as described in [this blog post I wrote](http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/using-subversion-to-automatically-publish-your-website/). I am running into issues right around the part where I su to the www-data user to run the following command:

```
svnadmin create /svn/repository
```

There is a check at the beginning of the script that makes sure it is running as root or sudo, and everything after that one command needs to be run as root. Is there a good way to run that one command as www-data and then switch back to root to finish up?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just use `su - www-data -c 'svnadmin create /svn/repository'` in your script run by root. So that only this command is run by www-data user.

---

*Update for future viewers*:

In case you receive a *`"This account is currently not available"`* error, consider using:

`su - www-data -s /bin/bash -c 'svnadmin create /svn/repository'`

( @Petr 's valuable mention about `-s` flag to accommodate `www-data` user's no login policy )

Comment: Yeah, it appears I forgot a basic rule of scripting... RTFM. Thanks!

Comment: Trying this, I get the error `This account is currently not available.`

Comment: I also get this error, but futbolsalas15's answer below works fine.

Comment: Use `su - www-data -s /bin/bash -c 'your_command'` to make this work. User www-data has shell `/usr/sbin/nologin` so without the `-s` parameter it leads to the error message.

Answer (score 77):

With 'su' is probably that request a password, and www-data doesn't have password. I recommend the command `sudo`:

```
 sudo -u www-data command
```

The condition is that your user must be root, or configurated in the sudoers file

Comment: Wow, why isn't this the selected answer?  Took me way too long to find this.

Comment: Yes, this is the easiest approach to running a command as www-data user.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**2 Possible approaches**:

---

1) **`sudo`** command:

In most cases you will have access to the `sudo` command and so the solution is simply:

`sudo -u target_user target_command`

---

2) **`su`** command (if sudo not installed. *`Ex. alpine-linux images`*):

`su - target_user -c 'target_command'`

In case you receive a ***'This account is currently not available'*** error, the user has a no login (shell access) policy in effect. If so, consider using:

`su - target_user -s /bin/bash -c 'target_command'`

(Based on @Petr 's valuable comment about `-s` flag to accommodate `www-data` user's no login policy)

Comment: the `sudo -u www-data target_command` version worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `su`:

```
   su [options] [username]

   The options which apply to the su command are:

   -c, --command COMMAND
       Specify a command that will be invoked by the shell using its -c.
```

Comment: It should be noted that su commands don't work with accounts that have disabled logins (such as www-data). You'll have to use sudo.